# Javascript filter and map where value for a key is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, lambda, ecmascript-6

So this is the original code....

```
selectedProducts = {
  10529814:false,
  10813521:true
};

this.selectedProducts.forEach((selected, value) => {
  if(selected) {
    this.discussionMessage.productIds.push(value);
  }
});
```

I wanted to rewrite it using filter/map technique, this is what I have up to now.

```
this.discussionMessage.productIds = this.selectedProducts.filter((selected, value) => selected)
  .map((product) => product);
```

But no matter what I change I can't seem to end up with a list of just the product ID's where its matched value is true.

Comment: you'll want filter and map (as you stated in the title) not just filter

Comment: Your array isn't valid. Is every entry an object or a string?

Comment: Your `selectedProducts` array is incorrect(unless its a lamda syntax). It needs to be array of object. Something like `[{10529814: false}, {10813521:true}]`

Comment: `this.selectedProducts.map((selected, value) => selected ? value : undefined).filter(value => value !== undefined);`

Comment: …or actually you need to map and then filter. Notice that `value` is actually an index.

Comment: I have updated the map and filter I currently have but it just returns {true} in an array rather than productId, see updated question.

Comment: Looks like you want something like this: `Object.keys(selectedProducts).filter(k => selectedProducts[k])` .This will return an array of productids which have a value of true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#filter` with `Object.keys()`. Iterate through each key of object `selectedProducts` and filter those values which are `true`.

```js
var selectedProducts = {10529814: false,10813521: true},
    result = Object.keys(selectedProducts).filter(k => selectedProducts[k]);
console.log(result);
```